# jQuery $.ajax and $.each looping through array

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, each

I'm making a call to the NY Times article search API and would like to append it to an HTML element as a new list element. However I'm having trouble using the $.each() function and iterating through the JSON data. I'm trying to post a hyperlink and article snippet.

The error I'm getting is "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token" at data.response in "$.each(data, function(i, data.response)"

```
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  method: 'GET',
}).done(function(data) {
  $.each(data, function(i, data.response){
    $.each(data.response.docs, function(index, object){
      $nytElem.append('<li class ="article">'+
      '<a href='+ data.response.docs[index].web_url +'>' + data.response.docs[index].headline.main +
      '</a><p>' + data.response.docs[index].snippet + '</p></li>')
    });
  });
  console.log(data);
}).fail(function(err) {
  throw err;
});
```

The API returns an object with an array containing information for 10 articles. I've only posted 2 here for brevity. Any help would be appreciated!

```
    {
      "status": "OK",
      "copyright": "Copyright (c) 2017 The New York Times Company. All Rights Reserved.",
      "response": {
        "docs": [
          {
            "web_url": "https://www.nytimes.com/aponline/2017/09/05/world/asia/ap-as-taiwan-politics.html",
            "snippet": "Taiwan's president has appointed a new premier seen as willing to reach out to rival China amid ongoing tense relations.",
            "blog": {},
            "source": "AP",
            "multimedia": [],
            "headline": {
              "main": "Taiwan Appoints New Premier Amid Tense China Relations",
              "print_headline": "Taiwan Appoints New Premier Amid Tense China Relations"
            },
            "keywords": [],
            "pub_date": "2017-09-05T06:06:43+0000",
            "document_type": "article",
            "new_desk": "None",
            "section_name": "Asia Pacific",
            "byline": {
              "original": "By THE ASSOCIATED PRESS"
            },
            "type_of_material": "News",
            "_id": "59ae3f007c459f246b621bb9",
            "word_count": 131,
            "score": 1,
            "uri": "nyt://article/ae5b0e41-75b2-5a7e-972d-8a76bcd5c11a"
          },
          {
            "web_url": "https://www.nytimes.com/reuters/2017/09/05/business/05reuters-hyundai-motor-china.html",
            "snippet": "South Korea's Hyundai Motor said it had suspended production at one of its China factories on Tuesday after a supplier refused to provide parts due to delays in payment - its second such incident in as many weeks.",
            "blog": {},
            "source": "Reuters",
            "multimedia": [],
            "headline": {
              "main": "Hyundai Hit Again by Supply Disruption in China, One Plant Halted",
              "print_headline": "Hyundai Hit Again by Supply Disruption in China, One Plant Halted"
            },
            "keywords": [],
            "pub_date": "2017-09-05T06:03:30+0000",
            "document_type": "article",
            "new_desk": "None",
            "byline": {
              "original": "By REUTERS"
            },
            "type_of_material": "News",
            "_id": "59ae3e427c459f246b621bb8",
            "word_count": 516,
            "score": 1,
            "uri": "nyt://article/c519de15-1040-5fc7-b1ad-8e73aed33a47"
          }
       ],
       "meta": {
         "hits": 16210307,
         "offset": 0,
         "time": 1016
        }
     }
  }
```

Comment: Where is `$.getJSON`? Where are you parsing said JSON seeing as you are not using `$.getJSON`?

Comment: @Script47 It's about $.ajax. Edited the title.

Comment: Exactly what URL are you using? You may be being blocked by the Same Origin Policy

Comment: Does the console provide any errors?

Comment: @Script47 The error is "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token" at data.response in "$.each(data, function(i, data.response)"

Comment: Shouldn't you have provided that?

Comment: @Script47 What do you mean?

Comment: Shouldn't you have told us that the console is showing that error originally to save us from guessing at what was wrong?

Comment: @Script47 Yes. I edited my post to include the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is all you need:

```
.done(function(data) {
    $.each(data.response.docs, function(i, doc) {
        var $a = $('<a>').attr("href", doc.web_url).html(doc.headline.main);
        var $p = $('<p>').html(doc.snippet);
        var $li = $('<li>').addClass("article").append($a).append($p);
        $nytElem.append($li);
    });
});
```

The second parameter of the function you pass to `$.each()` is going to contain each element of the array you passed. So what you do is pass `data.response.docs`, which is the array of articles, then use `doc` (or similar) as param, and `doc.[node]` to access the object and its children inside the array.

Comment: @000 Btw, JS has a native function for this: `data.response.docs.forEach(function(doc) { ... });`